# Spring boot and checking HTTP header presence

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-headers, spring-boot

I send along every REST call my custom header, which is (for instance) an authorization token. This token remains the same, as I do not need high security in this case. Can I use some simple way how to check every request coming to RestController whether it has this token among headers?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few ways:

1. Coding a `@ModelAttribute` in a `@ControllerAdvice` class, like this

   ```
   @ControllerAdvice
   public class HeaderFetcher {

       @ModelAttribute
       public void fetchHeader(@RequestHeader Optional<String> myHeader, Model model) {
         if header is present
           model.addAttribute("myHeader", the header);
         else
           throw exception
       }

   }
   ```

   Haven't tried this, though.
2. Using a filter
3. Using AoP

Comment: I was able to implement something like this (simple API key header check) quite nicely using @ControllerAdvice, so +1. In my case limited to specified controller classes using a custom annotation and `@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RequiresApiKey.class)`